# Kubernetes DaemonSet only on master nodes

Tags: kubernetes, daemon

Is there a way to run a Kubernetes DaemonSet only on master nodes? I know this is possible with deployments but can this behaviour be replicated with DaemonSets?

Answer (score 4):

I used a mix of nodeSelector and tolerations to achieve this. Here's the code -

```
  tolerations:
  - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
    operator: Exists
    effect: NoSchedule

  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/role: master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tolerations and node affinity in DaemonSet manifest files.

```
 Ex:
 ......
 tolerations:
 - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
   operator: Exists
 affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
            operator: Exists
   .....
```

Comment: How can I prevent the DS pods from scheduling on nodes? This helps with allowing them to be scheduled on masters.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a nodeSelector (similar to deployments) which selects only master nodes in daemonset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called Static pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/

Put the related kubernetes yaml file to Master's  `StaticPath` (normally it is /etc/kubernetes/manifests)

when the master started, these pods will be run automatically as daemonSet